# Detect connection-loss immedietly - Websocket - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, websocket

Is there a way to trigger a function immediately after the loss of the internet connection by a WebSocket.

`socket.onClose` and `socket.onError` does not trigger an immediate response that caters to my requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some situations in which the OS itself doesn't know that the connection was lost (such as network failures). This is sometimes known as half-open connections.

Since the OS doesn't know about the connection being closed, the browser or node server isn't notified and your WebSocket callback isn't called.

There's [a nice blog article about half-open connections here](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/05/detection-of-half-open-dropped.html).

You could mitigate the issue, for example by:

1. closing the socket yourself under suspicious circumstances (i.e., manually close the socket when the page loses focus).
2. implementing a client-side ping. The failure to send the ping would indicate to the program (and the OS) that the connection was lost, resulting in the `onclose` callback being called.

These options will always suffer from some delay. Network loss detection isn't easy.

Comment: I was thinking about the idea of pinging the server in a constant time delay. Ask this question to check whether are there any optimum solutions.

Comment: @NilankaManoj - I don't think you'll find an ideal solution. Networks suffer packet loss all the time. It takes a while for the TCP/IP stack to differentiate between an incidental packet loss and a broken connection. After all, the only difference is that a disconnection means that all packets will continue to be "lost", while (in contrast) with a single packet loss  the next attempt might succeed.